# What are these symlinks in /run/udev/watch?

Tags: linux, symlink, udev

I searched my computer for all the broken symlinks with the command

```
find / -xtype l
```

And it returned these among a few others:

```
/run/udev/watch/9
/run/udev/watch/8
/run/udev/watch/5
/run/udev/watch/3
/run/udev/watch/1
```

I listed that directory to see where those symlinks were pointing to and it looked like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct 14 07:19 1 -> b8:0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct 14 07:19 3 -> b8:1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct 14 07:19 5 -> b8:3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct 14 07:19 8 -> b8:2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Oct 14 16:11 9 -> b8:4
```

I have never seen something like this before and I am curious. What are these symlinks for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can find, the `/run/udev/watch` directory is leftover cruft from an initramfs before control is transferred to the real init.  The links in there are created as if they were in `../data`, where files like `b8:0` do exist (which describes a block devices).  I don't think the `watch` directory is used after boot is completed so those broken links shouldn't matter.  The whole `/run` tree is non-persistent so if your goal is to "fix" them, you'll need to figure out where in the initramfs they are generated and whether or not it is safe to remove them.

They are safe to just ignore.

Comment: I wasn't worried about them, just curious. But this answers my questions, thank you!